# Rosdep with custom package

Tags: catkin-make, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I have some ROS packages that contain dependencies on several packages that can be installed using rosdep install. On the other hand, one of those dependencies is with a custom package that contains only custom message definitions [my_custom_msgs].

The problem I have is that if I list "my_custom_msgs" as a run_depend / buid_depend, "*rosdep install -a*" fails saying *cannot locate rosdep definition for my_custom_msgs*, and, of course, if I remove it from the rund_depend / build_depend, I cannot build this package.

Is there a way of making rosdep install ignore dependencies on custom packages?

Cheers,
Aridane

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221835/rosdep-with-custom-package/) by [Aridane](https://answers.ros.org/users/8841/aridane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-12-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a way of making rosdep install ignore dependencies on custom packages?

No, but you can ask it to ignore packages which already exist in the source space of the target workspace (typically used with `--from-paths`):

```
rosdep install --ignore-src .. PKG
```

Anything that is a `run_` or `build_depend` and is already present in the source space will then be assumed to be fulfilling that dependency (and cause `rosdep` to not go and try to resolve it in the 'official' database).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-02**:
I realise this answer may be a bit pedantic, but I wanted to (implicitly) point out that there is no such thing as 'custom' packages for `rosdep`. It either checks all pkgs, or none. The only thing you can do is ask it to ignore things in the source space. The end result is the same though.

**Comment by [Aridane](https://answers.ros.org/users/8841/aridane/) on 2015-12-02**:
Don't worry about that, the answer is perfect!
Tahnk you very much.